# Angular $localize error after updating from version 14 to 15

Tags: angular, typescript, angular15

After updating our Angular app from version **14.0.4** to version **15.1.3** (also tried 15.1.2 before) we get the following error when trying to access the app:

```
Uncaught Error: It looks like your application or one of its dependencies is using i18n. 
Angular 9 introduced a global `$localize()` function that needs to be loaded.
Please run `ng add @angular/localize` from the Angular CLI.
(For non-CLI projects, add `import '@angular/localize/init';` to your `polyfills.ts` file.
For server-side rendering applications add the import to your `main.server.ts` file.)
```

So the problem is, that we already did those steps many updates ago. As you can see also from the description, this is sth. introduced with version 9. But we are running version 14 (and earlier) without any issues of this kind. The app compiles without errors and this is a run-time error.

I also tried re-running the mentioned command `ng add @angular/localize` after the version update, which just adds `@angular/localize` to the types array in the tsconfig, but it still fails with the same error.

I did the update following the recommended angular update website (https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=14.0-15.0) and also updated all other co-dependencies to the newest version (like material, NgRx, typescript etc.)

We use `$localize` either directly in components, for example:

```
 private readonly onLabel = $localize`:@@common_onLabel:`;
```

Or also in a shared way like this:

```
export const i18nD = $localize`:@@components_timeDisplay_shortDaysFormat:` as 'd';
```

I would appreciate any ideas or steps I could try, because I'm running out of ideas what to try next.

Comment: I got the same errors with Angular 16 actually.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like in recent versions they use a different system to include global `$localize` function.
It does not rely anymore on polyfill, but instead looks for the presence of `@angular/localize` among TS compiler configuration `types` array's items.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/24032

Try re-issuing schematic for adding $localize

```bash
ng add @angular/localize
```

or adding manually the type path in your `tsconfig.json` or whatever TS configuration file your project uses.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "types": ["@angular/localize"]  
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already tried that and still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure there's not any other TS configuration file overloading `types` declaration?
Where does `tsConfig` property point for your building target?

Comment: `tsConfig` points to `src/tsconfig.app.json` and this file then points to the 'main' tsConfig with `"extends": "../tsconfig.json"`.
I tried all sorts of combinations. Running `ng add @angular/localize` adds the above mentioned `"types": ["@angular/localize"]` to `tsconfig.app.json`. I also tried having it in both tsConfig file and also just in the 'main' tsConfig one. All combinations result in the same error.

Comment: I'd clear any cache and rebuild.
`.angular` directory and any other used by eventual tool if you're not calling ng-cli directly.

Comment: Really appreciate your effort! But unfortunately no luck :/ I cleared `.angular` and `node_modules`, re-installed and re-run and still nothing. I'm using node v.16.15.1 if that helps, but according https://angular.io/guide/update-to-version-15#v15-bc-01 this should be a high enough version. I will try to go through the update steps again, maybe I did some mistake along the way...

Comment: The only thing I can think of, is to check installed version of `ng-cli` assuring it's latest available **15.1.5**

Comment: It was on **15.1.3** but also changing it to **15.1.5** didn't change the outcome.

Comment: Since Angular v16 there is no need for the `polyfills.ts` file anymore. But adding the `import '@angular/localize/init';` adding to main.ts doesn't work? And without this import my `ng test` is actually failing (same error message as stated above). The workaround for me is adding this import line to the `jest.setup.ts` file. Hopefully this can be fixed within Angular 16 somehow, since this is the only reason I now need a jest.setup.ts file in Angular (for running Jest unit tests).

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the issue: It was an outdated `browserslist` configuration.
It was not touched for several years and looked like this:

```
"browserslist": [
  "> 1%",
  "last 1 version",
  "not ie > 0",
  "not ie_mob > 0",
  "safari >= 10",
  "not dead"
]
```

Removing it completely already fixed the issue. I'm still evaluating if I should set it to this `"defaults and supports es6-module"` or the Angular 15 defaults: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-browser-compatibility. Both seem to work and not cause the error mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I got error with

```
last 5 Chrome versions
last 5 Firefox versions
last 5 Edge major versions
last 5 Safari major versions
```

but okay with

```
chrome > 60
last 4 Chrome versions
last 4 Firefox versions
last 4 Edge major versions
last 4 Safari major versions
```

I do have the `@angular/localize` installed and imported.

I tried number more than 5, it ends with failure.